# Can I omit the article "the" in "A specific principle for the material supply"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Can I omit the article here? If yes, why? If no, why? Some translation software suggests me to.

> A specific principle for ***the*** material supply of small batch manufacturing
> areas

I think I can't omit because it is a singular common noun.

Someone pointed out that "specific principle" also needs an article (which is correct, thank you) and asked for context. The context is the title of a scientific paper.

Comment: What is the context? With proper grammatical structure, "specific principle" also needs an article because it is a singular common noun. But if this is abbreviated text, such as in business documents like invoices, articles are sometimes omitted.

Comment: Titles are sometimes abbreviated too. I am not sure what Lines is doing at the end though.

Comment: @mdewey Well, the question is: should they? I remove "lines" (I changed my title a little before posting it and this was a fragment).

Comment: What does "material supply" mean here? Is it domain-specific jargon for *the supply of raw materials to a manufacturing process*? This makes a difference, because whether or not to precede a noun by the definite article will often be affected by ***how well-known the noun [phrase] is***.

Comment: Note that particularly in recent decades, pluralised ***the materials supply business*** [has increasingly displaced singular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=material+supply+business%2Cmaterials+supply+business&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) ***the material supply business***. Which may or may not be relevant to the context here. I'm not *that* familiar with the jargon.

Comment: I actually researched a bit and it seems that for "real" stuff, materials is the proper plural for material. In the context of manufacturing, real stuff is meant (see, e.g., https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv163.shtml) @fumbleFingers It is domain-specific jargon for the supply system of raw materials to a manufacturing process. What would that change? If it is well-known, can the article be omitted? The specific principle is also well-known btw.

Comment: To my mind, *if and only if* the whole noun phrase "material supply of small batch manufacturing areas" is a "known collocation" within the industry is it appropriate to discard the article. That's to say - if it's "jargon", it probably doesn't require an article in your context. But domain-specific jargon usages aren't really suitable for ELL - in "normal English", you'd be talking about something more like ***the** supply of [raw] materials to manufacturing processes with small batch production runs*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, "material supply" is a domain-specific (let's say from manufacturing science) known "key word". However, the domain is naturally not entirely native-speaking and such word may or may not be actually correct english (it seems it should be at least "materials supply"). Also "small batch manufacturing areas" is a known key word from this domain. Then, I assume "material supply for small batch manufacturing areas" is what you call a "known collocation". Do you have a nice link that shows that you can omit articles for "known collocations"? I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: The supply of weapons to the enemy. The x of y takes article **the**. The joke of the day is [blank].

Answer (score 0):

Does the question "which material supply?" make sense in this conversation or text?

Or ...

Can you ask the question "which X" and "material supply" be a possible answer to it, for this conversation or text?  E.g. is it possible there's other values of X for "the X of small manufacturing areas" that the listener/reader might be concerned with?

If not, omit it.  If it does, keep it.

Comment: Do you mean like x = "product flow" --> the "product flow" of small manufacturing areas? This sentence makes sense. But I actually think I misunderstand you. Can you provide a link, maybe?

Comment: No link, the above is all from me.  What don't you understand?  Plug in "product flow" above and it still applies.

Comment: Is your point that we don't need an article if something is unique, e.g., Africa?

Comment: "Africa" is a proper noun (name of a country) and those don't take articles.

Comment: Africa is unique and thus is a proper noun.